# How to extract the year from the following texts using regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
1)2003 CPT Code: 90801 - Psychiatric Diagnos...
2)y1983 Clinic Hospital, first hospitalization, ...
```

whenever i try with `\b[\d]{4}\b` i'm getting both `2003` and `9080` from first statement and none from the second statement.

What i want as output is `2003` from first line and `1983` from second one

Answer (score 2):

You can reject for numbers on either side instead of matching on `\b`:

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/shVhnT/1/

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have `\b` at the start which means to match a number at word boundary and `y1983` doesnt match the criteria. You can try this instead

```
\b\D?(\d{4})\b
```

Check out the explanation at [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NnFq2e/1)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should capture the first group as the numbers:

```
(?<=\d\))[a-zA=Z]?(\d+)
```

Example I created for you is here:
https://regex101.com/r/RXJmFu/1

an example is:

```
s = ['1)2003 CPT Code: 90801 - Psychiatric Diagnos...',
'2)y1983 Clinic Hospital, first hospitalization, ...']

for match in s:
   print(re.findall(r'(?<=\d\))[a-zA=Z]?(\d+)', match)[0])
```

output:

```
2003
1983
```

Comment: That doesn't match `2019` in `blah blah 2019 blah` but matches `2019` in  `1)a2019123456`